# Laravel 5 model object retrieval

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel 5 and was wondering how model object retrieval works.

For instance I have a separate table that is referenced by another table and I want to get the records from that.

```
Item Table
Category Table
```

I was trying to extend the User model

```
Class Item extends Model {

    public function getCategory(){
         $category = Category::find($this->category_id);
         return $category;
    }
}
```

So when I try to access the object retrieved in my view,

```
{{ $item->getCategory()->name }}
```

I get the error

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$name
```

What am I doing wrong? And what is the best practice in doing this? I used to do this in Symfony and it works so I was wondering how its done in Laravel.

Any help and input would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you all.

Comment: Use relationships: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Mark! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the docs here's how I did it

```
Class Item extends Model {
   public function category()
     {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Category', 'id', 'category_id');
     }
}
```

And accessed the object in the view this way

```
{{ $item->category->name }}
```